# Negative lookbehind quantifier not fixed

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract data relating to a few categories from a text file (except for Categories A and B). The format of the substring would be something like

```
some text preceding Category C This is some text I'm aware of belonging to the categories
```

To handle this above, excluding Category A and B data I have a simple negative lookbehind regex as

```regex
(?<!Category A )(?<!Category B )This is some text I'm aware of
```

However, I also have some limited cases where `Category A/B` in the text would be followed  by a few characters (max 5). For instance:

```
some text Category A 1. This is some text I'm aware of belonging to the categories
```

So I tried changing the regex to:

```regex
(?<!Category A.{5})(?<!Category B.{5})This is some text I'm aware of
```

It works fine for exactly 5 characters after CatA/B, but it does not allow me to change `{5}` to `{0,5}` and complains:

> quantifier not fixed

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PyPi regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) to the rescue:

```
import regex
pattern = r"(?<!Category A.{0,5})(?<!Category B.{0,5})This is some text I'm aware of"
print(regex.findall(pattern, "This is some text I'm aware of"))
```

**Documentation**:

> Variable-length lookbehind
>
> A lookbehind can match a variable-length string.

See [Python proof](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEoNT21gqsgsaQktShPwVahSEnD3kbRObEkNT2/qFLBUa/aQMe0VhNF0AkqGJKRWawARMX5uakKJakVJQqe6rkKieWJRakK@WlKXAVFmXklGmAb9NIy81ISc3I0oDbpKCgR0K2p@f8/AA)

Answer (score 0):

Using Python re, if you want to match Category followed by an uppercase char except A and B, you can match C-Z followed by 0-5 chars and capture the text in a capture group.

```
\bCategory [C-Z].{0,5}\b(This is some text I'm aware of)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kAXTqG/1)

Comment: This would work for this particular example, however at this point I'm not really sure about the categories per se, hence I would prefer the lookbehind approach. Also, I think that makes the regex a little more intuitive.